# Accessing a particular element inside CDATA using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xml-parsing, cdata

I want access the  inside CDATA ONLY.  How can I parse nodes inside CDATA using javascript?

What I want to do is to modify the text inside  from AAA to BBB.

```
<b1><![CDATA[<html><h1>fdsa</h1><h2>AAA</h2></html>]]></b1>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no nodes or elements inside CDATA. The meaning of CDATA is to tell the reader of the XML: "the stuff in here might look like markup, but it isn't: it's ordinary plain text, and I don't want it parsed."

So CDATA tells the parser to provide the application with an unstructured text string containing angle brackets. If the application believes that, contrary to what it has been told, this string actually contains markup, then it can put it through a parser to determine its structure.